# Spring ClassPathResource(file).getInputStream() not releasing resource immediately

Tags: java, spring, unix, resources, resource-leak

**I've presented that problem as possible JDK bug: [Is JDK ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream broken? (unclosed resources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496044/is-jdk-classloader-getresourceasstream-broken-unclosed-resources)**

I'm reading properties (with some interval) from file by:

```
    try (InputStream propertiesInputStream = 
            new ClassPathResource(FILENAME).getInputStream()) {
                loadedProperties.load(propertiesInputStream);
            }
```

but when I go to `/proc/MY_PROCESS_ID/fd` and list opened resources I see my `FILENAME` properties file opened even 100 times or more. This is risky as 1024 is default limit on most unix machines.

It decrases sometimes to 0 (looks like closed by finalize() with GC call).

Why that resources do not dissapear immediately after leaving try-with-resources block?

/proc/TOMCATPID/fd shows **a lot of** (currently > 1000):

```
lr-x------ 1 MyUserName TomcatUserName 64 Feb 13 01:04 973 -> /opt/project/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/conf/configurationServices.properties
lr-x------ 1 MyUserName TomcatUserName 64 Feb 13 01:04 974 -> /opt/project/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/conf/configurationServices.properties
```

I read this properties 2 times per minute, which is consist with about 1000 opened descriptors after several hours.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you show what you see if `./fd`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Updated question with fd listing (ls -l)

Comment: Does your app open the resource in a loop?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis 2 times per minute in TimerTask scheduled by `new Timer()`. But I think it is not releated to not closing.

Comment: Consider also adding your Linux distribution and Java versions.

Comment: Or delete the question :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Actually question is valid. I removed all other places where that file is accessed, 100% sure that code is rebuilt and it is that code etc. and still - resource usage is growing. I will try to test with minimum example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Actuly I made new question, I suppose this is JDK bug or misuse, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496044/is-jdk-classloader-getresourceasstream-broken-unclosed-resources